# Why is DOM manipulation not just handled by another module in the module/mediator/facade pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture

I've just finished listening to Nicholas Zakas's [great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw) on the module/mediator/facade design pattern. I want to use this pattern for an upcoming project, but I've got a question that I can't nut out:

Why does Zakas let the DOM manipulation and AJAX communication be handled by the application core? Given the philosophy of the design pattern, couldn't these just be treated as modules?

I feel like the fact that I'm asking this means that I misunderstand something fundamental about the module/mediator/facade design pattern. Hopefully someone can fill me in.

Comment: I did not see the talk, but the most important rule for using design patterns is : "Do it only, if it makes common sense". If separating DOM or AJAX from app core to module does not help in any matter, there is no reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks @libik, but to me it does seem to make sense that DOM and AJAX would be handled by seperate modules - it seems like it'd make things easier. Obviously the top developer's don't do this though, and there must be a reason why...

Comment: Maybe it is because of "loose coupling" and "high cohesion" principles, which means - stick together things which belongs to each other and separate things which do not. If something cannot exist/be used without another class/library, there is usually no reason to separate it.

Comment: Ah, because the majority of the modules use the DOM and Ajax at some point? This makes sense! Thanks @libik

Comment: yes, something like that... You can even make module, which counts the result of an expression and returns it, but it is still better to let the Java itself do it. (it is a little extreme situation, but it is good to demonstrate, that not everything has to be in modules)

Comment: Yep, that's a good point, cheers